# Django 1.4 debug_toolbar and htmltidy with checking html5 syntax

Tags: django, html, htmltidy, django-debug-toolbar

htmltidy check html 4 syntax errors and it shows me boring messages like

```
Current page have following errors:

Position    Error or Warning
line 5 column 5 
    Warning: <meta> proprietary attribute "charset" 
line 5 column 5 
    Warning: <meta> lacks "content" attribute
```

because I'm use html5.

How to say htmltidy check syntax as html5 validator?

`Django 1.4`
`debug_toolbar 0.9.4`
`debug_toolbar_htmltidy 0.1.1`